# https://appr.tc is down. How to set up own signaling server/ room server URL?

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android, apprtc, apprtcdemo, webrtc-ios

I'd developed a video calling app on Android using WebRTC and was using the https://appr.tc as the signaling server (Room Server URL). But according to https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/H7XuZfgkGH0 apprtc is now taken down. When I run the AppRTC demo app I get the following error:

```
Connection Error
Non-200 response to POST to URL: https://appr.tc/join/room_id32864 : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Could someone please show the way on how to change the Room Server URL or setup my own Room Server URL? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of apprtc remains available on github:
https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

You might want to read this blog post about whether to use it though:
https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-signaling-server-not-use-apprtc/
The project has been effectively abandoned for years and you will have a hard time finding support.

Comment: Thanks, I was in double minds on using this and your answer cleared my doubts. What are your thoughts on Twilio WebRTC Go?

Comment: Which video calling api would you recommend, I want to create  a one to one video calling app for Android (Java) and iOS (Swift)?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to https://hub.docker.com/r/pegome/apprtc It has support for SSL and inbuilt TURN server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).